# Is this method for converting Unicode chars truly endian agnostic?

Tags: c++, c++11, endianness

I'm just a little skeptical of my own code (and tests, naturally) and would like someone to verify if this is approach truly endian agnostic.

Internally in a cross platform project I'm using UTF-32 (std::u32string) for the string type. But to make dealing with I/O on different platforms easier I'm converting UTF-32 to UTF-8 before sending any text to a file or over the wire.

I would say this approach is endian agnostic. UTF-8 is a byte orientated encoding which means endianness of the computer doesn't affect the byte stream. The large 32-bit characters are being converted to UTF-8 in the order they appear in the string before being sent to the stream.

Here's snippets of code from a Json String class to provide an example of what I'm doing

```
/**
*   Provides conversion facilities between UTF-8 and Unicode32 strings.
*/
typedef std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> UnicodeConverter;

/**
* Converts the JSON value to a valid JSON string.
* @param the UTF-8 stream to write to.
* @returns The UTF-8 stream.
*/
inline std::ostream& VToJson(std::ostream& os) const override { return EscapeJsonString(os << STRING_JSON_QUOTE) << STRING_JSON_QUOTE; }

/**
*   Streams a json string in its escaped form.
*   @param os the UTF-8 stream to write to.
*   @returns the original stream.
*/
std::ostream& JsonString::EscapeJsonString(std::ostream &os) const 
{
    UnicodeConverter conv;
    for each (char32_t c in i_Value)
    {
        // Check if character is a special character
        if (c == '\\')
            // Output escaped rev solidus
            os << "\\\\";
        else if (c == '/')
            // Output escaped solidus
            os << "\\/";
        else if (c == '\b')
            // Output escaped backspace
            os << "\\b";
        else if (c == '\f')
            // Output escaped formfeed
            os << "\\f";
        else if (c == '\n')
            // Output escaped new line
            os << "\\n";
        else if (c == '\r')
            // Output secaped carriage return
            os << "\\r";
        else if (c == '\t')
            // Output escaped tab
            os << "\\t";
        else if (is_unicode_control(c))
        {
            // Output escape
            os << "\\u";

            // Output hex representation
            std::stringstream str;
            str << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << std::hex << c;
            os << str.str();
        }
        else
            // Normal character
            os << conv.to_bytes(c);
    }
    return os;
}
```

Comment: I can't see any endian-ness issue. However, the special characters checking seems superfluous wrt. to avoiding interpretation of those characters, since the general treatment of control characters would be enough. Also (but mostly academic issue) will only work when the C++ execution character set is based on ASCII.

Comment: I will replace those string constants with an appropriate u32string constant in the future. 

The explicit escapes are more for debugging purposes really. The Json spec allows for these characters to be explicitly escaped. It's easier to add a little extra code and see common control codes in a text editor or wireshark than it is to keep on looking up hex values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this approach can be implemented endianness agnostic, since UTF-32 is only used on a system with the same endianness, while in every case where it interfaces with a system that may have different endianness UTF-8 is used - and UTF-8 is built on a byte stream (therefore there is no endianness).

However, the conversion itself is endian-sensitive and must be implemented correctly so that endianness does not become a problem (e.g. no `memcopy` but arithmetic shifts instead). It should be reasonable to assume that your standard library implementation does this conversion correctly.

To add some clarification as to why this code shall be unaffected by endianess (22.5/4):

> For the facet `codecvt_utf8`:
>   - The facet shall convert between UTF-8 multibyte sequences and UCS2 or UCS4 (depending on the
>   size of `Elem`) within the program.
>   - Endianness shall not affect how multibyte sequences are read or written.
>   - The multibyte sequences may be written as either a text or a binary file.

The `endianess` member of the `codecvt_mode` enumeration type is only intended for reading/writing UTF-16 and UTF-32 multibyte sequences.

Comment: [They aren't **his** routines](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert/to_bytes), per se.

Comment: Unicode converter is a typedef of the STL conversions facilities. 
    `typedef std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> UnicodeConverter;`

I can't seem to find any specific information regarding if STL requires the conversion to be endian agnostic.

Comment: I overlooked that typedef -.-

Comment: Having a look at the Microsoft website, they seem to think that to/from big endian is the default for STL. (At least that's how they've implemented it, need to double check for clang and gcc)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee292252.aspx

Comment: [That `enum`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/codecvt/codecvt_mode/) is part of standards C++.